# How to invoke multiple commands via EB's NodeCommand?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lerna

### Context

Given a simple Node app on AWS's Elastic Beanstalk (like [eb-node-express-sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-node-express-sample)) and the default `nodecommand.config` file like this:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
    NodeCommand: npm start
```

### Question

How can I invoke multiple bash commands in place of `npm start`? I'd love to be able to do the following:

```
    NodeCommand: echo 'Hello' && npm start
```

or:

```
    NodeCommand: |
      echo 'Hello'
      npm start
```

but it seems that everything after the first word is actually passed in as a single argument, leading to the following output in `/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log`:

```
'Hello' && npm start
'Hello' && npm start
'Hello' && npm start
...

# Logged repeatedly as the server tries and fails to start,
# apparently invoking `echo "'Hello' && npm start"` each time...
```

Is there any way to get around this silly limitation and directly run multiple bash commands?

### Motivation

I have a Lerna app that, rather than having any useful `start` script in the root directory, has a `start` script in `packages/api/`. My particular need here is to be able to change directories before running `start`, but I'm looking for a generic solution to this problem of running multiple commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My workaround is to add a script to `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "start:eb": "echo 'Hello' && npm start"
}
```

Usage:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
    NodeCommand: npm run start:eb
```

---

In case it's relevant to others, I got here because of an ambiguous `502 Bad Gateway` error from nginx due to the server not starting, but absolutely nothing in `/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log`. I finally realized it was due to the NodeCommand being mangled by AWS.